# Connect to IMAP Exchange with starttls in python 2.7 (not 3)

Tags: python, python-2.7, starttls

I just found that(not sure) python 3 support starttls connect but not python 2.7

But my current big python code runs on python 2.7 so cant immediately move to 3.

So, can I connect to microsoft exchange server with imap and starttls security?

Need more details ?

Comment: I want starttls security enabled for imap. that page shows starttls for smtp

Answer (score 4):

Some time has passed, but I hope this helps others.  You can connect to Exchange over TLS using imaplib with either Python 3 or Python 2.

Python 3 has the IMAP4.starttls() method, Python 2 does not.  For Python 2, use the IMAP4_SSL subclass instead.  The following snippets are from working solutions that connect to office365.com over TLS.

#### Python 3

```
from imaplib import IMAP4
. . .

    def _connect(self, host, username, password, use_tls=False):
        """Establishes an IMAP connection, optionally over TLS."""
        try:
            src = IMAP4(host)
            if use_tls:
                src.starttls()
            src.login(username, password)
        except . . .
```

#### Python 2

```
from imaplib import IMAP4, IMAP4_SSL
. . .

    def _connect(self, host, username, password, use_tls=False):
        """Establishes the IMAP connection, optionally over TLS."""
        try:
            src = IMAP4_SSL(host) if use_tls else IMAP4(host)
            src.login(username, password)
        except . . .
```

Comment: For me, `IMAP4` raises an exception (abort) with the following message: `unexpected response: 220 HE1PR02CA0073.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 21 Jun 2016 07:55:27 +0000`. Using `IMAP_SSL` raises with `SSL: unknown protocol` which I think is because it doesn't use starttls. This behavour is basically the same in both 2 and 3.

Comment: `IMAP_SSL` exception is: `SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645)`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: me?  2.7.12 and 3.5.2.

Comment: Hi @pythonator.  I hope it was clear in my snippets that you should pass use_tls=True (and override the default value) in both cases. I can confirm that these both work for _me_ with Office365.

Comment: Sorry for not replying. I think I got it to work, but now I've forgotten how I did it. :(  It seems I can't accept your answer... too late?